# c# optimising out some log statements

Tags: c#, performance

I have a couple of sections of code that are very processor intensive. I have debug statements in there for internal deployments and testing but when I deploy to my customer sites I would like to do a build that doesn't have these. I currently use:

```
 ifIsDebugEnabled()
```

to wrap the log messages but this is also taking up processor time and when I commented all the logging out the performance improved. Is there a standard way to go about this or are there other things I can do instead?

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To optimize out method calls, you can put the `ConditionalAttribute` on methods. Like this:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
void SomeDebugMethod(string message) { 
    // ...
}
```

Calls to this method will be removed if the code is compiled in another configuration than DEBUG.

This is a cleaner looking way than using directives like `#ifdef DEBUG .. #endif`, if you can afford to put your Debug logic in Methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
#if DEBUG
#endif
```

in your code to skip out code from the release build...

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your code with preprocessor directives like this:

```
#if DEBUG
// debug code
#endif
```

There's a complete list of available directives [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional compilation:

```
#if DEBUG
// code to log here
#endif
```

The code will only be included in the compile if you're running DEBUG mode.  You can also create your own conditional compilation directives using the project properties page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preprocessor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) to cause the debug mode check to happen at compile-time... so when you compile without DEBUG defined it will completely skip your debug code, causing no performance hit.

```
#define DEBUG
// ...
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug");
#endif
```

Comment: You don't have to `#define DEBUG` - it's done by default on DEBUG builds